# JQuery Mobile Swipe .load .prev and .next

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I'm trying to figure out how to write the jQuery so that upon swiping right it will load the previous sibling and swiping left it will load the next sibling. I'm a new to JS.

HTML/HAML

```
#gallery
   #active-pane
   #pane1.pane
     Pane 1
   #pane2.pane
     Pane 2
   #pane3.pane
     Pane 3
   #pane4.pane
     Pane 4
```

I have the below JQuery working. But I really would like it to just load the prev and next siblings. Swipe a .pane and get the next or previous.

```
$("#pane1").swiperight(function() {
    $('#active-pane').load("/additional-info #pane2").fade("slow");
    return false
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it by changing page with slide transition on swiperight/swipeleft events.

```
 $(".ui-page").swiperight(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage( $('#'+getNextPageId()), 
                         { transition: "slide", reverse:false});
 });


 $(".ui-page").swipeleft(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage( $('#'+getPrevPageId()), 
                         { transition: "slide", reverse:true});
 });
```

full demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nachiket/MsP4u/